# How to make a variable global from inside a function

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I'm working on a new library, and I am trying to make a function: `toGlobal(variable)`, it will take any variable, local, or global, and make it a global variable. The only problem is that I can't find a method to make a local variable become global.

Comment: Sounds like a solution to a problem that doesn't exist. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: assign it to window, i.e `window.variable`

Comment: @John3136 I have had the problem with occasionally needing a local variable to become global, and it's needed for undisclosed sections of the library itself.

Comment: Thanks Felix for pointing me to the correct question.